# How to list the hieararchy with unique sets of data upto a given level in VBA macro in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet (name:"ABC") with the below data -

```
User_Name   User_ID     Manger_Name  
ab          1           pq  
bc          2           gh  
pq          3           xy  
xy          4           yz  
yz          5           bm  
ef          6           ab  
lm          7           bc  
gh          8           bm  
bm          9           bm
```

I have to extract a unique list of managers and their corresponding managers' mapping with "bm" being the highest level of manager in a different sheet(name: "PQR"). The final mapping list should look like this:

```
Manger_Name   Manager_ID  VP_Name  VP_ID   
pq            3           xy       4  
xy            4           yz       5  
ab            1           pq       3  
bc            2           gh       2  
yz            5           bm       9  
gh            8           bm       9
```

I am very new to vba coding. please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Please share the code and where you are having problems.

Answer (score 0):

"extract a unique list of managers" - you can do this with *remove duplicates*

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-HP010073943.aspx

"and their corresponding managers' mapping" - you should be able to use VLOOKUP with the list of unique managers to get their "mapping"

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is a code snippet I keep to paste uniques from one column into another
.

```
Option Explicit
Sub PasteUniques()

' hiker95, 07/26/2012 - original code
' http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?649576-Extract-unique-values-from-one-column-using-VBA
' Scheballs, 12/26/2013 - edited code
' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20785233/how-to-list-the-hieararchy-with-unique-sets-of-data-upto-a-given-level-in-vba-ma

Dim d As Object, c As Variant, i As Long, lr As Long
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
'Get Ranges from input boxes
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim SourceRange As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Set SourceRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
                "With your Mouse select the Column/Range that contains the SourceRange.", _
                    Title:="RANGE WITH DUPLICATES TO BE UNIQUIFIED", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        If SourceRange Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

Dim PasteRange As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Set PasteRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
                "With your mouse please select the cell location to paste your uniques.", _
                    Title:="SPECIFY PASTE LOCATION", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        If PasteRange Is Nothing Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

'-------------------------------------------------------------------
'Build Dictionary and Paste
'-------------------------------------------------------------------
c = SourceRange
For i = 1 To UBound(c, 1)
  d(c(i, 1)) = 1
Next i

PasteRange.Resize(d.Count) = Application.Transpose(d.keys)

End Sub
```